# Proving Operator Equaility with Polarization Identity

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Given linear operators $A,B$ on a Hilbert Space $H$ with
$ \langle x,Ax \rangle = \langle x,Bx \rangle $
for all $x$ in $D(A)=D(B)$.

My script says that via the polaritazion identity this implies $A=B$. How would one use the polarization identity to show this result?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need the domains to be dense. Then for any $y\in D(A)$
$$
\langle y,Ax\rangle=\frac14\,\sum_{k=0}^3i^k\langle y+i^kx,A(y+i^k x)\rangle
=\frac14\,\sum_{k=0}^3i^k\langle y+i^kx,B(y+i^k x)\rangle=\langle y,Bx\rangle. 
$$
As $D(A)=D(B)$ is dense, you get that $\langle y,Ax\rangle=\langle y,Bx\rangle$ for all $y$, which implies $Ax=Bx$.

---

> So how do you come to the form of the polarization identity you use?

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^3i^k\langle y+i ^kx,A( y+i ^kx)\rangle
&=\langle y+x,A(y+x)\rangle
+i \langle y+i x,A(y+ix)\rangle\\[0.2cm]
&\qquad-\langle y-x,A(y-x)\rangle
-i \langle y-i x,A(y-ix)\rangle\\[0.2cm]
&=\langle y,Ay\rangle+\langle x,Ax\rangle+\langle y,Ax\rangle
+\langle x,Ay\rangle\\[0.2cm]
&\qquad+i\langle y,Ay\rangle+i\langle x,Ax\rangle+\langle y,Ax\rangle
-\langle x,Ay\rangle\\[0.2cm]
&\qquad-\langle y,Ay\rangle-\langle x,Ax\rangle+\langle y,Ax\rangle
+\langle x,Ay\rangle\\[0.2cm]
&\qquad-i\langle y,Ay\rangle-i\langle x,Ax\rangle+\langle y,Ax\rangle
-\langle x,Ay\rangle\\[0.2cm]
&=4\langle y,Ax \rangle.
\end{align}

Comment: +1 Nice. Isnt it enough to have $Range(A-B) \subseteq D(A) = D(B)$ rather than density by choosing $y = (A-B)x$ ? But  strange condition though !

Comment: Yes, but I wouldn't know what to do with that condition other than the fact it works here. While density of an unbounded operator is pretty standard.

Comment: @MartinArgerami   But isn't $\langle y, Ax \rangle = \frac{1}{4} \sum_{k=0}^{3}i^k ||y+i^kAx||$. So how do you come to the form of the polarization identity you use?

Comment: You are missing a square. In any case, the equality just holds, and I have edited the straightforward computation in. Or you could notice that $[y,x]=\langle y,Ax \rangle$ is a sesquilinear form and a new proof is not needed.